# Time taken for a system to return to it's original state

Tags: coordinate-systems, time, chaos-theory, complex-systems, ergodicity

Consider the following system:

> There are N particles (point-like particles) of $1$ Kg  each in a Sphere of radius $R$ centered at origin in three dimensions. Randomly assign these N particles their starting positions inside this sphere and a direction vector of magnitude $1$. What is the average time taken for the system to return to it's original state?

(I would like to point out that I have constructed the above problem for the purpose of creating large numbers with physical relevance). Collision between particles follow conservation or energy and momentum. It might be possible that there is a starting position where the system never returns to its original state. If such a scenario is indeed possible then we might need to consider spherical particles with radii $r_1,\ldots,r_N$ (or for simplicity unit spheres with $R$ large enough) or finite time steps(From Poincaré recurrence theorem, time taken to return to original state will always be finite). I was unable to find any sources related to this problem. Is there an estimate for any other kind of boundaries, like a cube?

Comment: How can the particles collide and be centered all at the origin simultaneously? Do you mean that they are centered in some small volume $\Delta V$?

Comment: The sphere, inside of which all particles are present have the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$, the sphere is centered at the origin, not the particles. No two particles can occupy the same position inside the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the conditions with sufficient completeness, so it is impossible to model the problem without making further assumptions.

For example, when you say the particles are inside a sphere, do you mean a notional spherical boundary of a region in space or a physical sphere? If the latter, what are the physical properties of the sphere? If the sphere was made of plasticine, the particles might collide with the sphere and stick to it, thus never returning to their original positions. If the sphere were perforated, the particles might pass through it.

Is the sphere evacuated or filled with some form of gas? Is it thermally insulated? Is it in space or in Earth's gravity? Is it and the particles neutrally charged?

What do you mean by a direction vector of magnitude 1? What is the relative magnitude of the sphere? What energies are assigned to the particles?

And so on- there are far too many unspecified details about the set-up; you need to specify the problem unambiguously.

And finally, when you say 'original state', do you mean that each particle will be in its original position with its original velocity? How can that happen in a real system, given that there will be energy lost from the particles to the sphere and to the wider environment?

Ignoring all that, let's consider that the particles are balls in a lotto machine that shakes them all up at random. How long would the machine have to run on average for there to be two identical configurations of balls? Let's suppose there are fifty balls, each moving on average at 1m/s in a sphere of volume 1 cubic metres. and let's suppose that by 'identical' configurations we mean that each ball must be within a micrometer of its original position, with a speed that is within one micrometer per second of its original speed and that we'll forget about orientation.

The very crudest 'back of an envelope' calculation I can imagine is to say that the chance of a ball being within a micrometer of its original position at any instant is the ratio of one cubic micrometer to one cubic meter, which is very small, something like 0.000000000000000001. The chance of all 50 balls being in a micrometer of their original position is the probability of one raised to the power of fifty. Likewise, the chance of one ball having a speed that is within one micrometer per second of its original speed might be 0.000000001. And the probability of all the balls would be that to the power of fifty. So leaving aside orientation, I think the probability, P, of being in its original config at any given instant is 0.000000000000000000000000001 to the power of fifty. You would then have to factor in how often the system moves from one configuration state to another. If you said that it did so y times per second, then you could estimate the time required to go back to its original config as being 1/(P/y) seconds, which would be a huge number.